# Lexical Analyzer not getting the next character

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

So I am working on a project where we are making a small compiler program but before I can move on to the other parts I am having troubles with getting the lexical analyzer to output anything after '\BEGIN' afterwards I debugged it and it seems the value is stuck in a loop where the condition is saying the next character is always a newline. Is it because I haven't added the pattern matching yet to the defined tokens?

Here is the code

```
import java.util

//import com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.Expression.Parser.Token
/*Lexical analyzer will be responsible for the following:
- finds the lexemes
- Checks each given character determining the tokens
* */
class MyLexicalAnalyzer extends LexicalAnalyzer {
  //Array full of the keywords
//val SpecialCharacters = List(']', '#', '*', '+', '\\', '[', '(',')', "![", '=')

  val TEXT = "[a-z] | _ | 0-9 | [A-Z]:"
  private var sourceLine: String = null
  private val lexeme: Array[Char] = new Array[Char](999)
  private var nextChar: Char = 0
  private var lexLength: Int = 0
  private var position: Int = 0
  private val lexems: util.List[String] = new util.ArrayList[String]

  def start(line: String): Unit = {
    initializeLexems()
    sourceLine = line
    position = 0
    getChar()
    getNextToken()
  }
  // A helper method to determine if the current character is a space.

  private def isSpace(c: Char) = c == ' '

  //Defined and intialized tokens
    def initializeLexems(): Any =  {
   lexems.add("\\BEGIN")
    lexems.add("\\END")
   lexems.add("\\PARAB")
  lexems.add("\\DEF[")
    lexems.add("\\USE[")
  lexems.add("\\PARAE")
   lexems.add("\\TITLE[")
    lexems.add("]")
   lexems.add("[")
   lexems.add("\\")
   lexems.add("(")
  lexems.add(")")
    lexems.add("![")
   lexems.add("=")
    lexems.add("+")
  lexems.add("#")
  }
//val pattern = new regex("''").r
  def getNextToken() ={
    lexLength = 0
    // Ignore spaces and add the first character to the token
    getNonBlank()
    addChar()
    getChar()
    // Continue gathering characters for the token
    while ( {
      (nextChar != '\n') && (nextChar != ' ')
    }) {
      addChar()
      getChar()
    }
    // Convert the gathered character array token into a String
    val newToken: String = new String(lexeme)
    if (lookup(newToken.substring(0, lexLength)))
      MyCompiler.setCurrentToken(newToken.substring(0,lexLength))
  }
  // A helper method to get the next non-blank character.
  private def getNonBlank(): Unit = {
    while ( {
      isSpace(nextChar)
    }) getChar()
  }

  /*
    Method of function that adds the current character to the token
    after checking to make sure that length of the token isn't too
    long, a lexical error in this case.
   */
  def addChar(){

      if (lexLength <= 998) {
        lexeme({
          lexLength += 1; lexLength - 1
        }) = nextChar
        lexeme(lexLength) = 0
      }
    else
        System.out.println("LEXICAL ERROR - The found lexeme is too long!")
    if (!isSpace(nextChar))
      while ( {
      !isSpace(nextChar)
    })
        getChar()
    lexLength = 0
    getNonBlank()
    addChar()
  }

  //Reading from the file its obtaining the tokens
  def getChar() {
    if (position < sourceLine.length)
      nextChar = sourceLine.charAt ( {
        position += 1;
        position - 1
      })
    else nextChar = '\n'

  def lookup(candidateToken: String): Boolean ={
    if (!(lexems.contains(candidateToken))) {
      System.out.println("LEXICAL ERROR - '" + candidateToken + "' is not recognized.")
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

> ```
>  else nextChar = '\n'<- this is where the condition goes after rendering the first character '\BEGIN' then just keeps outputting in the debug console as listed below.
> ```

[image]
This is what the debug console it outputting after '\BEGIN' is read through
Can anyone please let me know why that is? This happens after I keep stepping into it many times as well.

Here is the driver class that uses the lexical analyzer

```
import scala.io.Source

object MyCompiler {
  //check the arguments
  //check file extensions
  //initialization
  //get first token
  //call start state
  var currentToken : String = ""

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val filename = args(0)
    //check if an input file provided
    if(args.length == 0) {
      //usage error
      println("USAGE ERROR:  Must provide an input file. ")
      System.exit(0)
    }
    if(!checkFileExtension(args(0))) {
      println("USAGE ERROR: Extension name is invalid make sure its .gtx ")
      System.exit(0)
    }

    val Scanner = new MyLexicalAnalyzer
    val Parser = new MySyntaxAnalyzer

    //getCurrentToken(Scanner.getNextToken())
    //Parser.gittex()
    for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()){
      Scanner.start(line)
      println()
    }


    //.......
    //If it gets here, it is compiled
    //post processing

  }
  //checks the file extension if valid and ends with .gtx
  def checkFileExtension(filename : String) : Boolean =  filename.endsWith(".gtx")

  def getCurrentToken() : String = this.currentToken
  def setCurrentToken(t : String ) : Unit = this.currentToken = t
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `sourceLine`?

Comment: @RobinGreen It is the current line being read into an entire string

Comment: But what is the value of it that you are seeing in the debugger? You need to tell us what your input is, or we cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @RobinGreen the output of sourceline is "\BEGIN" or look at the newly uploaded picture above

Answer (score 1):

The code is operating as it is supposed to. The first line contains only the string `\BEGIN` so the lexical analyser is treating the end of the first line as an '\n' as shown in this method:

```
def getChar() {
  if (position < sourceLine.length)
    nextChar = sourceLine.charAt ( {
      position += 1;
      position - 1
    })
  else nextChar = '\n'
```

However, the comment directly above that method does **not** describe what the method actually does. This could be a hint as to where your confusion lies. If the comment says it should read from the file, but it is not reading from the file, maybe that's what you've forgotten to implement.

Comment: I see what you mean so I would add additinal code that checks through the file instead of checking through the list?

Comment: So I added the driver class which does use and go through a file input